# MatLab 7.10.0 movement comparison of minimum values in a series of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a several large matrices (~500x650) and I am interested in finding the minimum value of only one column  and its corresponding row number, then comparing it to the same column in the other martices (i.e., compare column 5 in matrix 1 to column 5 in matrix 7). The minimum value will change rows and values each time, but I am only interested in finding out how many rows the minimum value moved from the location in the previous matrix. I do not care about what the minimum value is, I just want to know how many rows the value moved. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you so much for your time and assistance.

Comment: Use the second output argument of `min` to get the index.

Answer (score 0):

min function finds the minimum in each column and the related index. then you can compare them.
example:

```
M =

    0.3922    0.7060    0.0462
    0.6555    0.0318    0.0971
    0.1712    0.2769    0.8235

[C,I]=min(M)

C =

    0.1712    0.0318    0.0462

I =

     3     2     1
```

you can do the same for other dimensions:

```
[C,I]=min(M,[],2)

C =

    0.0462
    0.0318
    0.1712


I =

     3
     2
     1
```

then you can do this:

```
 [~,idx]=min(C)

idx =

     2
```

the minimum is placed in I(idx),idx:

```
M(I(idx),idx)

 = 0.0318
```

which is equal to

```
min(min(M))
```